# Confused with the OpenMP threadprivate variable's initialization

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm learning OpenMP these days and I just met the "threadprivate" directive. The code snippet below written by myself didn't output the expected result:

```
// **** File: fun.h **** //
void seed(int x);
int drand();
// ********************* //

// **** File: fun.c **** //
extern int num;
int drand()
{
    num = num + 1;
    return num;
}
void seed(int num_initial)
{
    num = num_initial;
}
// ************************ //

// **** File: main.c **** //
#include  "fun.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <omp.h>

int num = 0;
#pragma omp threadprivate(num)

int main()
{
    int num_inital = 4;


    seed(num_inital);
    printf("At the beginning, num = %d\n", num);  // should num be 4?
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(2) schedule(static,1) copyin(num)
    for (int ii = 0; ii < 4; ii++) {    
        int my_rank = omp_get_thread_num();
        //printf("Before processing, in thread %d num = %d\n", my_rank,num);
        int num_in_loop = drand();
        printf("Thread %d is processing loop %d: num = %d\n", my_rank,ii, num_in_loop);
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
// ********************* //
```

Here list my questions:

1. Why the result of `printf("At the beginning, num = %d\n", num);` is `num = 0` instead of `num = 4`?
2. As for the parallel for loop,  multiple executions produce different results one of which is:

```
Thread 1 is processing loop 1: num = 5
Thread 0 is processing loop 0: num = 6
Thread 1 is processing loop 3: num = 7
Thread 0 is processing loop 2: num = 8
```

It seems that `num` is initialized to 4 in the for loop which denotes that the `num` in `copyin` clause is equal to 4. Why `num` in `printf("At the beginning, num = %d\n", num)` is different from that in `copyin`?

3. In [OpenMP website](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu104.html), it said

   > In parallel regions, references by the master thread will be to the copy of the variable in the thread that encountered the parallel region.

   According to this explanation, Thread 0 (the master thread)  should firstly contains `num = 4`.  Therefore, loop 0's output should always be:  `Thread 0 is processing loop 0: num = 5`. Why the result above is different?

My working environment is win10 operating system with VS2015.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is within the `fun.c` compilation unit. The compiler cannot determine the `extern int num;` variable is also a TLS one.

I will include directive `#pragma omp threadprivate(num)` in this file:

```
// **** File: fun.c **** //
extern int num;
#pragma omp threadprivate(num)
int drand()
{
    num = num + 1;
    return num;
}
void seed(int num_initial)
{
    num = num_initial;
}
// ************************ //
```

In any case, the compiler should warn about it at the linking phase.

Answer (score 0):

The `copyin` clause is meant to be used in OpenMP teams (eg. computation on computing accelerators).

Indeed, the [OpenMP documentation](https://www.openmp.org/spec-html/5.0/openmpsu108.html#x141-6080002.19.6.1) says:

> These clauses support the copying of data values from **private or threadprivate variables** on one implicit task or thread to the corresponding variables on other implicit tasks or threads **in the team**.

Thus, in you case, you should rather use the clause `firstprivate`.

Please note that the version (5.0) of the OpenMP documentation your are reading is probably not supported by VS2015. I advise you to read an older version compatible with VS2015. The results of the compiled program are likely to be undefined.